# Help in understanding equation and reference request for multivariate GLM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, references, dirichlet-distribution

I am reading page 5 in this document: http://epub.wu.ac.at/4077/1/Report125.pdf

It's about Dirichlet regression in a GLM-like setting. What I don't understand is

- each observed $y_c$ (of which there are $n$) is assumed to be Dirichlet-distributed with some shape parameters $a_1,...,a_C$.
- The author then writes $g(a_c) = \eta_c = X^c\beta^c$ (see equation 5)
- He changes the likelihood function by inserting $X^c\beta^c$ in place of $a_c$ (see equation 6).

My questions are, how come $g(a_c) = X^c \beta^c$? $a_c$ is a vector of $C$ parts, while $X^c\beta^c$ is a matrix.

And even if that were true, then how come in equation 6 he substitutes $a_c$ for $X^c\beta^c$, given that we just said that $g(a_c)$ is what it equals?

Finally, what are some good references to understand the theory behind this paper?